# How to convert the prepare statement sql string with an Object to the exact sql string?

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am using spring. I have many update steps, Is there a way to used `batchUpdate` for this?

**Original**

```
jdbcTemplate.update("UPDATE USER SET name = ? WHERE user_id = ?", new Object[] {name, id});  
jdbcTemplate.update("UPDATE USER2 SET name = ? WHERE user_id = ?", new Object[] {name, id2});  
jdbcTemplate.update("UPDATE USER3 SET name = ? WHERE user_id = ?", new Object[] {name, id3});
```

**How to used batchUpdate**

```
getJdbcTemplate().batchUpdate(sql);
```

Because the parameter for `batchUpdate` is `Array[]`. How to convert the prepare statement SQL string with an Object to the exact SQL string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`int\[\] batchUpdate(String... sql)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#batchUpdate-java.lang.String...-) is the wrong method for the job.
It is intended for a case where you have a bunch of different SQL statements without parameters, that you want to execute in one go.

You need to use on of the other `batchUpdate` methods.

If you don't need to control the batch size
[`public int[] batchUpdate(String sql, List<Object[]> batchArgs)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#batchUpdate-java.lang.String-java.util.List-)
should work fine. The call would look like this:

```
jdbcTemplate.update(
    "UPDATE USER SET name = ? WHERE user_id = ?", 
    Arrays.asList(
        new Object[] {name, id},
        new Object[] {name, id2}, 
        new Object[] {name, id3}
    )
);
```

Also take a look at the other variants that allow to provide a batch size, the type of arguments or parameter setters which allow to set the parameters for each part of the batch individually.

[See also this example](https://mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-batchupdate-example/).

Comment: Yes, I have a bunch of different SQL statements. The SQL is contains the symbol “?”. Is there has the utility to transfer SQL statement and variable object to a pure SQL string?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that your SQL statements are differen't

Comment: I don't think there is utility for that. String.replace might be sufficient as long as the statements with their values don't contain `?` themselves.

Comment: Yes, finally I used String.replace for that. For the variable `String`, I add 'quote' mark to wrap around, others will just replace.

Comment: But I recently learned, without `prepare statement`, this is bad for database performance.